# Autofac Wcf - Inject service depending on data within SOAP Request

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a WCF Service with the following operation contract:

```
[OperationContract]
Response SearchEntities(Query query);
```

This operation takes a request that contains a specified Entity like so:

```
[DataContract]
public class Query
{
    [DataMember]
    public string SearchTerm { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Entity { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool ExactMatch { get; set; }
}
```

Based on the value contained within the `Entity` property, one the following properties is populated within this response:

```
[DataContract]
public class Response
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Asset> Assets { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Stage> Stages { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Sector> Sectors { get; set; }
}
```

Terrible design, I know! However. I am using Autofac.Wcf as my service factory to inject dependencies. Normally I would use a common Interface and Generics to determine a service to use based on the `Entity` value like so:

```
public interface IEntitySearch<T>
{
    Response Search(Query query);
}
```

The above interface would have several implementations for each of the Lists within the response. Using a design pattern such as a service location I could determine which service to use (all of which inherit from `IEntitySearch<T>`, something like:

```
public IEntitySearch ResolveSearcher(Query query)
{
    switch(query.Entity)
    {
        case "Assets":
            return _container.Resolve<AssetSearch>();
        case "Stages":
            return _container.Resolve<StageSearch>();
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

While this works, a more elegant solution (I believe) would be to customize the Autofac container per request for this particular operation, depending on the data contained within the request.

IE: Before the WCF pipe line sends the request to the service implementation, is it possible to examine the request data and customize how the container resolves dependencies. That way I can avoid exposing dependency resolution within my service layer.

Is this possible?

If another DI library other than Autofac has a solution for this, I will happily change our DI framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't *personally tried this* but I think a direction you can go down is to combine:

- Using [`OperationContext.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.operationcontext?view=netframework-4.7.1) to get the current request message data.
- Specifying a custom [`IServiceImplementationDataProvider` for Autofac](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Wcf/blob/develop/src/Autofac.Integration.Wcf/IServiceImplementationDataProvider.cs) that tells Autofac which WCF interface to host for that request.
- Using a lambda registration for your service implementation to switch the backing service based on `OperationContext.Current`.

You can see two examples of the `IServiceImplementationDataProvider` by looking at the [`DefaultServiceImplementationProvider`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Wcf/blob/develop/src/Autofac.Integration.Wcf/DefaultServiceImplementationDataProvider.cs) - the one that works in Autofac WCF hosting by default; and[`MultitenantServiceImplementationDataProvider`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Multitenant.Wcf/blob/develop/src/Autofac.Multitenant.Wcf/MultitenantServiceImplementationDataProvider.cs), which is more about generating a proxy to enable multitenant WCF hosting.

While neither of these use `OperationContext.Current` to determine the actual backing service, you can build on the ideas:

- Look at the [Autofac.Multitenant.Wcf](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Multitenant.Wcf) implementation. You may be able to use it as-is. The point of the instance data provider there is that WCF grabs on to the *concrete type* of the service being hosted and if you try to swap types out from under it, you get errors. The multitenant support fools WCF by creating a proxy type and your implementation type can be swapped out under the proxy. Note the `MultitenantServiceImplementationDataProvider` doesn't actually tie anything to a tenant or tenant ID; it's only about that proxy.
- In your `.svc` file specify a service interface rather than any individual concrete implementation since you'll be swapping out the implementation.
- Use a lambda registration to figure out your implementation.
- Make sure your service is `InstanceContextMode.PerCall` to ensure things get swapped out on a per request basis.

The registration might look something like this:

```
builder.Register(ctx => {
  var context = OperationContext.Current;
  var type = DetermineTypeFromContext(context);
  return ctx.Resolve(type);
}).As<IMyServiceInterface>();
```

The [Autofac WCF](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/wcf.html) and [Autofac Multitenant](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/multitenant.html#wcf-integration) section on WCF may also help.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you're trying to move your problem just to another place. Why would making decision based on request at low-level WCF is better than switch in `SearchEntities` method? It's much worse ;-)

I would consider to use `IEntitySearch` factory/provider e.q.`IEntitySearchProvider` (it's not so much better but always).

```
public interface IEntitySearch
{
    bool IsMatchQuery(Query query);
    Response Search(Query query);
}

// without service locator
public class EntitySearchProvider : IEntitySearchProvider
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IEntitySearch> _searchers;

    public EntitySearchProvider(IEnumerable<IEntitySearch> searchers)
    {
        _searchers = searchers;
    }

    public IEntitySearch GetSearcher(Query query)
    {
        // last registered 
        return _searchers.LastOrDefault(i=>i.IsMatchQuery(query))
            ??  throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

or

```
public interface IEntitySearchProvider
{
    IEntitySearch GetSearcher(Query query);
}

public class EntitySearchProvider : IEntitySearchProvider
{
    private readonly IComponentContext _container;

    public EntitySearchProvider(IComponentContext container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IEntitySearch GetSearcher(Query query)
    {
        switch(query.Entity)
        {
            case "Assets":
                return _container.Resolve<AssetSearch>();
            case "Stages":
                return _container.Resolve<StageSearch>();
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

with

```
public class WcfService
{
    private readonly IEntitySearchProvider _provider;

    public WcfService(IEntitySearchProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public Response SearchEntities(Query query)
    {
        var searcher = _provider.GetSearcher(query);
        return searcher.Search(query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify why it would be worse to move the decision to low level WCF?

Comment: **Harder to maintain.** Binding business logic within WCF it's just bad idea. You're going to move entry point of handling business logic to place where it shouldn't be placed. It may be harder to migrate from WCF to another technology.

**Problems with DI container.**  1. Container should be immutable for service host instance (or tentacle) lifetime. 2. Creating containers per request would be expensive (even with some kind of cache). 
3. Optional updating "root" container for request is also bad idea [link](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/811).
4. What about singletons ?